# Get all data in html table into array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, html-table, push

So far I can get all generic text data into an array, but I'm struggling with the select boxes within the table cell. So far in my jQuery I have this

```
$('.image-button').click(function(){
        var myTableArray = [];

        $("table#imgList tr").each(function() {
            var arrayOfThisRow = [];
            var tableData = $(this).find('td');
            if (tableData.length > 0) {
                tableData.each(function() {
                    if($(this).has('select').length){
                        arrayOfThisRow.push($(this + ' select option:selected').text());
                    } else {
                        arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text());
                    } 
                });
                myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
            }
        });

        console.log(myTableArray);
    });
```

It fails once it goes into the if has select statement, with an error I have not seen before:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLTableCellElement]

I'm not really sure what is wrong with the above code so if anyone can help I'd much appreciate that.

Comment: And what's the relevant HTML that you're working with, or on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you can't append a string to an object to create the selector. You need to use `find()` to get the `select` within the current `td`:

```
arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).find('select option:selected').text());
```

Secondly, you can shorten your code by using `map()` to create the array:

```
$('.image-button').click(function(){
    var myTableArray = $("table#imgList tr").map(function() {
        var arrayOfThisRow = $(this).find('td').map(function() {
            return $(this).has('select').length ? $(this).find('select option:selected').text() : $(this).text();
        }).get();
        return arrayOfThisRow;
    }).get();
    console.log(myTableArray);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
arrayOfThisRow.push($(this + ' select option:selected').text());
```

should be changed to:

```
arrayOfThisRow.push($('select option:selected', this).text());
```

or:

```
arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).find('select option:selected').text());
```

Comment: take care thumb's up and you can _mark the tick_ to green for rory's answer. Good luck.