# Jquery selector to get all dropdown values, issues for 2 dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, dropdown

HTML Table

> Row#1 : *Col 1* [`Country DropDown`]    |   *Col #2* [`StateDropDown`]
>
> Row#2 : *Col 1* [`Country DropDown`]    |    *Col 2* [`StateDropDown`]

table has 2 `dropdownlists`, for `Country` & `State` - this works on one dropdown, *but its disabling other/state dropdowns as well!*

Problem is, while *both* USA and Aust have `diff states selected` text, but in `col2` endup with *same* selected `State` ID/value `3` (If I select California, Perth is also Disabled!, hence my code is disabling them as duplicates since its comparing the selected value and not text) for e.g. this selection disables Perth..

```
[USA]      ->    [California]  (value = 3)
[Australia] ->   [Perth]       (*also* has value= 3) so its disabled
```

**How to do this as a `unique combination` of both country & state in each row? or just compare texts of the dropdowns?...**

1. i.e. Option1, **how to check if both `Country ID + State ID Value already exist`**?
2. Option2, Just compare the selected texts (feels half baked)

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nooberz/xv97cf5g/10/)

```
// Javascript Does not disable States previously selected
$("#CountryTable").on('change', '.State', function() {
var dropDownText = $('#CountryTable .State select').not(this).map(function()                {
 return this.SelectedText; // does not work this.val() works but useless
}).get();
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
var otherDropdowns = $('.State').not(this);
```

otherDropdowns.find('option[value=' + selectedValue + ']').prop('disabled', true);
});

---

```
<table id="CountryTable">
<tbody id="CountryTableBody"> 
    <tr class="row">
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="1">Country A</option>
                <option value="2">Country B</option>
                <option value="3">Country C</option>
            </select>               
        </td>

        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="1">State 1</option>
                <option value="2">State 2</option>
                <option value="3">State 3</option>
                <option value="4">State 4</option>
                <option value="5">State 5</option>
            </select>               
        </td>           
    <tr>  <!-- in JS prevent previous selection -->
    <tr class="row">
       <td>
            <select>
                <option value="1">Country A</option>
                <option value="2">Country B</option>
                <option value="3">Country C</option>
            </select>               
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="1">State 1</option>
                <option value="2">State 2</option>
                <option value="3">State 3</option>
                <option value="4">State 4</option>
                <option value="5">State 5</option>
            </select>               
        </td>          
    <tr>    
</tbody>
```

---

*** Image to show something *similar*... not accurate

[image: Sample to show - prevent duplicate Combinations of the Cascading drowpdowns]

---

Comment: I think I'm on something... But before going too far: I would need to know what is dynamically created. Up to now, I assumed that the first column (countries) are not dynamic... And I forgot about the obviously dynamic options for the 2nd column. (lol) But I'm on something any way. I will check again tomorrow. This is a tought one!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette  i am unable to set the disabled in two cases - `1)` when  New rows are cloned/appended dynamically - when those rows are appended to the table. and `2)` additionallly on first run, I am unable to set the disable on the current ` $this dropdown` state or country. *I am wondering if its easier to [collect all the](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27145521/6085193) combinations on the page, and prevent the same combination values*

Comment: What you wrote in italic : Is exactly what I'm on...

Answer (score 2):

This is not a perfect solution which you just can copy/paste, but it's getting real close to what you want.

I made it as a whole function with 4 arguments:

1. The real `table`, preferably an `id`
2. The `td`, preferably a `class`
3. The hidden `table` to be cloned, preferably an `id`
4. The new row `button`, preferably an `id`

Leaving you free to name your things like you want in the HTML and not caring about to fix the MULTIPLE places where those 4 are used in the script.

**Now... This is just a good start.**
In fact, when user changes from "Country A" to "Country B", the state dropdown should be different!

This is the only issue I left... Since I don't know how you want to load those options.

It took me quit a lot time... I did it because I couldn't believe that such a "simple" request can be that complex... I had to crush it
;).

So here is the code (JS only) and a working [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/WpWQEr?editors=1011) demo.

```
var excusiveSelect = function(tableID,rowCLASS,dummyID,cloneBtn){   // Preferably ID, CLASS, ID, ID

  console.clear();

  // Cloning function
  var cloneRow = function(){
    var newrow = $(dummyID).find(rowCLASS).clone();
    $(tableID).append(newrow);
    refresh_mapping();
  };

  // Generate new lines
  $(cloneBtn).on("click",cloneRow);

  // ================================================================================ INITIALISATION
  // Selection mapping
  var row_count;
  var row_map = {};

  // Get select clas names per colums
  var col_count = $(rowCLASS).first().find("td").length;
  var col_classes = [];
  for(i=0;i<col_count;i++){
    col_classes[i] = $(document).find(rowCLASS).first().find("select").eq(i).attr("class").split(" ").join(".");
  }
  console.log("SELECT CLASSES: "+JSON.stringify(col_classes));

  var refresh_mapping = function(){
    row_count =  $(document).find(rowCLASS).length-1;
    console.log("ROWCOUNT: "+row_count);
    for(i=0;i<row_count;i++){

      row_map["row_"+i] = {};
      $(tableID).find(rowCLASS).eq(i).find("select").each(function(index){

        // Get the select classes as object attribute.
        var thisClasses = $(this).attr("class").split(" ").join(".");

        // For each row/select get the selected index.
        row_map["row_"+i][thisClasses] = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
      });
    }
    console.log("VALUES MAPPING: "+JSON.stringify(row_map));
  }

  cloneRow();

  // ================================================================================ FROM COLUMN #1

  $(document).on("change","."+col_classes[0],function(){
    console.log("\n======================================================= Country change\n");

    refresh_mapping();

    // Disables options already selected in ALL col_classes[1] where col_classes[0] is the same
    for(i=0;i<row_count;i++){

      if( ( row_map["row_"+i][col_classes[0]] == $(this)[0].selectedIndex ) 
         && (  $(this).closest(rowCLASS).index() != i ) ){

        $(this).closest(rowCLASS).find("."+col_classes[1]+" option").eq( row_map["row_"+i][col_classes[1]] ).attr("disabled",true);

        // Else enable the option if not self
      }else{
        if( $(this).closest(rowCLASS).index() != i ){
          $(this).closest(rowCLASS).find("."+col_classes[1]+" option").eq(i).attr("disabled",false);
        }
      }
    }

  });

  // ================================================================================ FROM COLUMN #2

  $(document).on("change","."+col_classes[1],function(){
    console.log("\n======================================================= State change\n");
    console.clear();
    refresh_mapping();

    thisIndex = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;               // Option selectedIndex
    thisRowIndex = $(this).closest(rowCLASS).index();     // Row index

    // If same country...
    var thisCol0index = $(this).closest(rowCLASS).find("."+col_classes[0])[0].selectedIndex;


    $(tableID).find("."+col_classes[1]).each(function(){
      if( $(this).closest(rowCLASS).find("."+col_classes[0])[0].selectedIndex == thisCol0index ){

        // Zap tout les disabled
        $(this).find("option:not(:eq(0))").attr("disabled",false);

        // Use mapping to disable based on col_classes[0]
        for(i=0;i<row_count;i++){
          if( row_map["row_"+i][col_classes[0]] == thisCol0index ){

            $(this).find("option").eq(row_map["row_"+i][col_classes[1]]).attr("disabled",true);
          }
        }

      }
    });
  });
  // ================================================================================
}

// Init!
excusiveSelect("#CountryTable",".row","#DummyTable","#newRow");   // Preferably ID, CLASS, ID, ID
```

Comment: thanks for taking a shot at this. Yeah I know right, *such a simple problem has me stumped too* :) I have the same problem cropping up in [your sample too](https://ibb.co/dbH6wF) I have attached the picture.. I have upvoted you, its close... but I still need the soln... not sure how to go about it!

Comment: I see... What you show is exactly the "bug" I left. That is because the disabling are made two ways 1- from the country select, which checks for already selected for the same country. 2- from the state select, which disables the selected options in the other select (and same country). Now when you change country, it does not resets the selections... Since it SHOULD dynamically CHANGE those options elements. So that is where I stopped.

Comment: here is a nice link to [getting both values](http://jsfiddle.net/nooberz/Lr5pq/327/)...